# Probability of maximum is less than maximum of probability??

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem about probability theory, but I get in trouble.

The problem is :

[image]

At first, I tried to solve it using 'Kolmogorov's inequality' and 'Chebyshev's inequality', but the problem is that there is NO assumption about finite variance!
So I have to solve another way and I tried, but I have no idea how to solve it.
Please give me any advice!
Thanks.